# angular ng-repeat and array from js

Tags: angularjs

I'm tring to repeat an array in the html

html:

```html
   

<div class="personWrapper" ng-repeat="message in messages">
  <p>{{message}}</p>
 </div>
```

js:

```js
var app = angular.module('matcherApp', [ "ngRoute", "ngStorage" ]);

app.config(function($routeProvider) {
 $routeProvider.when('/Messages', {
  templateUrl : 'menu/messages.php',
  controller : 'messagesController'
 })
});
    app.controller('messagesController', function($scope, $localStorage) {

 console.log("im in messages page!!!");
 var messagesUsers = [];
 $.post("db.php", {
  'messagesWindow' : "messagesWindow",
  'myProfileId' : JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("myProfileDetails")).id
 }, function(data) {
  data = $.parseJSON(data);
  angular.forEach(data, function(key, value) {
   angular.forEach(key, function(key2, value2) {
    messagesUsers.push(key2.Name);
   });
  });

  console.log(messagesUsers);
  $scope.messages = messagesUsers;
 }).fail(function() {
  alert("error bringing messages data");
 });

});
```

the console.log show me:

im in messages page!!!
["a","b"]

that works with all different controllers in the same app.
its not showing me on the dom any loop.
what am i doing wrong? thanks.

Comment: what is your question/problem?

Comment: its not show me on the dom any loop....

Comment: Can you show your controller code?

Comment: Please post more of your html and controller-code

Comment: i updated the question to the full code... the problem is not in the route or in the post, becouse i have more pages that works fine. and the post bring me back exactly the data i need... ( iprint it also to the console) ,do you know what i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Works for me! Look

```js
var app = angular.module('MessagesApp', []);
app.controller('MessagesController', function($scope) {
  $scope.messages = ["a", "b"];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="MessagesApp" ng-controller="MessagesController">
  <div class="personWrapper" ng-repeat="message in messages">
    <p>{{message}}</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

JS Code looks like below:

```
var app = angular.module('modelapp', []);
app.controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
      $scope.emplist = ["john", "marry", "jaison"];
});
```

HTML Code:

```
<div ng-app="modelapp" ng-controller="ctrl">
    <div ng-repeat="data in emplist">
         <p>{{data}}</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

It will load entire list, You can add class for div as per design, Even you can track index number also by using `$index` directive.